Hide and Resize Panel in GridBagLayout during runtime
I have a JPanel panelOpslog with a GridBagLayout.
On this panel there are 2 Panel. 1 on the top and one on the bottom.
panelSearchOpsLog
---------------------
panelShiftTeamLogging

panelSearchOpsLog is set to grow to the bottom and to the right
        panelOpslog = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Opslog", null, panelOpslog, null);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panelOpslog = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelOpslog.columnWidths = new int[]{1155, 0};
        gbl_panelOpslog.rowHeights = new int[]{212, 401, 0};
        gbl_panelOpslog.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelOpslog.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelOpslog.setLayout(gbl_panelOpslog);

....

        panelShiftTeamLogging = new JPanel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panelShiftTeamLogging = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panelShiftTeamLogging.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panelShiftTeamLogging.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panelShiftTeamLogging.gridy = 1;
        panelOpslog.add(panelShiftTeamLogging, gbc_panelShiftTeamLogging);
        panelShiftTeamLogging.setLayout(null);

....

        panelSearchOpsLog = new JPanel();
        panelSearchOpsLog.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        panelSearchOpsLog.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, new Color(255, 255, 255), new Color(160, 160, 160)), "Search Opslog", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panelSearchOpsLog = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panelSearchOpsLog.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panelSearchOpsLog.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_panelSearchOpsLog.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panelSearchOpsLog.gridy = 0;
        panelOpslog.add(panelSearchOpsLog, gbc_panelSearchOpsLog);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panelSearchOpsLog = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelSearchOpsLog.columnWidths = new int[]{129, 0, 0};
        gbl_panelSearchOpsLog.rowHeights = new int[]{30, 160, 0};
        gbl_panelSearchOpsLog.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelSearchOpsLog.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelSearchOpsLog.setLayout(gbl_panelSearchOpsLog);

Now I want an option to set panelShiftTeamLogging to invisible to that Panel 1 can use the complete space.
I put this code in an actionlistener from a button. Its hides panelShiftTeamLogging but panelSearchOpsLog is not resized
        btnHideShow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean isVisible = panelShiftTeamLogging.isVisible();
                panelShiftTeamLogging.setVisible(!isVisible);

                panelOpslog.revalidate();
                panelOpslog.repaint();
                
                panelOpslog.getParent().revalidate();
                panelOpslog.getParent().repaint();
            }
        });

PS: I want to stay with GridBagLayout
EDIT: a working example
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel panelTop;
    private JButton btnHideShow;
    private JPanel panelBottom;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPaneOnToPanel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPaneOnBottomPanel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test window = new Test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1002, 533);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{988, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{465, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
        
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_tabbedPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_tabbedPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_tabbedPane.gridx = 0;
        gbc_tabbedPane.gridy = 0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, gbc_tabbedPane);
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", null, panel, null);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{983, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{189, 206, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);
        
        panelTop = new JPanel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panelTop = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panelTop.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panelTop.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_panelTop.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panelTop.gridy = 0;
        gbc_panelTop.weighty = 0; // Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggestion
        gbc_panelTop.gridheight = 1; // Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggestion
        panel.add(panelTop, gbc_panelTop);
        
        GridBagLayout gbl_panelTop = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelTop.columnWidths = new int[]{449, 0};
        gbl_panelTop.rowHeights = new int[]{21, 0, 0};
        gbl_panelTop.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelTop.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelTop.setLayout(gbl_panelTop);
        
        btnHideShow = new JButton("Hide / Show the lower panel. The Table should also use the space from the lower panel");
        btnHideShow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean isVisible = panelBottom.isVisible();
                panelBottom.setVisible(!isVisible);

                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                
                panel.getParent().revalidate();
                panel.getParent().repaint();
            }
        });
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnHideShow = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnHideShow.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_btnHideShow.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc_btnHideShow.gridx = 0;
        gbc_btnHideShow.gridy = 0;
        panelTop.add(btnHideShow, gbc_btnHideShow);
        
        scrollPaneOnToPanel = new JScrollPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPaneOnToPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_scrollPaneOnToPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_scrollPaneOnToPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_scrollPaneOnToPanel.gridy = 1;
        panelTop.add(scrollPaneOnToPanel, gbc_scrollPaneOnToPanel);
        
        table = new JTable();
        String[] columns = {"Column A", "Column B"};
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(columns, 60));
        scrollPaneOnToPanel.setViewportView(table);
        
        panelBottom = new JPanel();
        panelBottom.setLayout(null);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panelBottom = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panelBottom.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panelBottom.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panelBottom.gridy = 1;
        gbc_panelBottom.weighty = 1.0; // Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggestion
        panel.add(panelBottom, gbc_panelBottom);
        
        scrollPaneOnBottomPanel = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneOnBottomPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 973, 233);
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        scrollPaneOnBottomPanel.setViewportView(textArea);
        panelBottom.add(scrollPaneOnBottomPanel);
    }
}



Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem. So all you need is a frame with two panels and a button. When you click the button, one of the panels will be made invisible and the other should shift to fill its space. Once we help you get this working you can apply the solution to your real application. The idea is to simplify the problem to make it easier to solve.

@camickr i added a working example.

scrollPane_1.setBounds(0, 0, 973, 233); -- this is not helping you my friend.

Finally I found a solution.
The problem was the initial set for the minimal row heigth
int[] rowHeights = {447, 100}; // Initial row heights

The solution is now to change these heigth when I click the button
    private void togglePanel() {
        if (isMaximized) {
            // Maximize upper panel
            gbl_mainPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{mainPanel.getHeight(), 0}; // Hide lower panel
        } else {
            // Restore original layout
            gbl_mainPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{mainPanel.getHeight() -100, 100}; // Set original row heights
        }

        // Apply the new layout settings
        mainPanel.setLayout(gbl_mainPanel);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        
        isMaximized = !isMaximized;
    }

additionally a component listener is required for resizing the frame
        // Add ComponentListener to adjust row heights on resize
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (!isMaximized) {
                    gbl_mainPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{mainPanel.getHeight(), 0}; // Update row heights on resize
                } else {
                    gbl_mainPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{mainPanel.getHeight() -100, 100}; // Update row heights on resize
                    
                }
                
                mainPanel.revalidate();
                mainPanel.repaint();
            }
        });

Below you can find the working solution
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel upperPanel;
    private JPanel lowerPanel;
    private boolean isMaximized = true;
    private GridBagLayout gbl_mainPanel;
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public Test() {
        setTitle("TabbedPane Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800, 600);

        // Create and set GridBagLayout for mainPanel
        gbl_mainPanel = new GridBagLayout();
        double[] columnWeights = {1.0};
        double[] rowWeights = {1.0, 1.0};
        int[] rowHeights = {447, 100}; // Initial row heights
        gbl_mainPanel.columnWeights = columnWeights;
        gbl_mainPanel.rowWeights = rowWeights;
        gbl_mainPanel.rowHeights = rowHeights;
        mainPanel = new JPanel(gbl_mainPanel);

        // Upper Panel with GridBagLayout
        upperPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        // Create and add table
        String[] columnNames = {"Column 1", "Column 2"};
        Object[][] data = new Object[60][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            data[i][0] = "Row " + (i + 1) + " Col 1";
            data[i][1] = "Row " + (i + 1) + " Col 2";
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // Create and add button
        JButton toggleButton = new JButton("Toggle");
        toggleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                togglePanel();
            }
        });

        // Create separate GridBagConstraints for each component
        GridBagConstraints gbcButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbcButton.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbcButton.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5); // Padding around the button
        gbcButton.gridy = 0;
        gbcButton.gridx = 0;

        GridBagConstraints gbcTable = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbcTable.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbcTable.weightx = 1.0;
        gbcTable.weighty = 1.0;
        gbcTable.gridy = 1;
        gbcTable.gridx = 0;

        // Add components to upperPanel
        upperPanel.add(toggleButton, gbcButton);
        upperPanel.add(tableScrollPane, gbcTable);

        // Lower Panel with Absolute Layout
        lowerPanel = new JPanel(null); // Null layout for absolute positioning
        JTextArea textAreaLower = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane textAreaScrollPaneLower = new JScrollPane(textAreaLower);
        textAreaScrollPaneLower.setBounds(10, 10, 760, 75);

        lowerPanel.add(textAreaScrollPaneLower);

        GridBagConstraints gbcUpperPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbcUpperPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbcUpperPanel.weightx = 1.0;
        gbcUpperPanel.weighty = 0.9;
        gbcUpperPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbcUpperPanel.gridy = 0;

        GridBagConstraints gbcLowerPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbcLowerPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbcLowerPanel.weightx = 1.0;
        gbcLowerPanel.weighty = 0.1;
        gbcLowerPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbcLowerPanel.gridy = 1;

        // Add panels to mainPanel
        mainPanel.add(upperPanel, gbcUpperPanel);
        mainPanel.add(lowerPanel, gbcLowerPanel);

        // Add mainPanel to tabbedPane
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("mainPanel", mainPanel);
        getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        // Add ComponentListener to adjust row heights on resize
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (!isMaximized) {
                    gbl_mainPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{mainPanel.getHeight(), 0}; // Update row heights on resize
                } else {
                    gbl_mainPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{mainPanel.getHeight() -100, 100}; // Update row heights on resize
                    
                }
                
                mainPanel.revalidate();
                mainPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void togglePanel() {
        if (isMaximized) {
            // Maximize upper panel
            gbl_mainPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{mainPanel.getHeight(), 0}; // Hide lower panel
        } else {
            // Restore original layout
            gbl_mainPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{mainPanel.getHeight() -100, 100}; // Set original row heights
        }

        // Apply the new layout settings
        mainPanel.setLayout(gbl_mainPanel);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        
        isMaximized = !isMaximized;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}



(1-) There is no need for a ComponentListener. There is no need to reset the row heights. This is NOT the proper way to use layout managers. In the solution below you were shown how to use a GridBagLayout more effectively.

Maybe its not the propper way, but at least it is working. ;) And if someone has the same problem, he/she can find here an alternate soltution. Even if it was downvoted because its not "the state of the art". Btw there was no answer how it works with my sample code above. The one with the absolute layout in the bottom panel. Sometimes an absolute layout is nessessary. But this is only my humble opinion. Thx for your answer anyway. :)

Sometimes an absolute layout is nessessary - no it isn't if you understand the design of layout managers and understand how they should be used. There is absolutely no need for the ComponentListener. Layout management is done automatically when coded properly. By the way you were given a proper solution using layout managers. So if the solution wasn't exactly what you wanted, then you should have started with that "working" solution and then make changes to provide additional functionality. Then if the code breaks you have better code to post with your question.

The problem is that you tried to retrofit the proposed solution into your poor designed original code.

You're forgetting to set the GridBagLayout's weighty to a reasonable value, 0 for the button and 1.0 for the others. Also, avoid setSize and setBounds as this can run you into significant trouble. Also, avoid null layouts. A working example could be something like so:

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Test2 extends JPanel {
    public static final int PREF_W = 1000;
    public static final int PREF_H = 650;
    
    public Test2() {
        JButton hidePanelBtn = new JButton("Hide/Show Panel");
        String[] columns = {"Column A", "Column B"};
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 60);
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        JScrollPane scrollPane11 = new JScrollPane(table);
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Hello World", 12, 50);
        final JScrollPane scrollPane12 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        hidePanelBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            scrollPane12.setVisible(!scrollPane12.isVisible());
            Test2.this.revalidate();
            Test2.this.repaint();
        });
        
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        
        mainPanel.add(hidePanelBtn, gbc);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainPanel.add(scrollPane11, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        mainPanel.add(scrollPane12, gbc);
        
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
        // not sure why you want a JTabbedPane, but here one is...
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("New Tab", mainPanel);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(tabbedPane);        
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Test2::createAndDisplay);
    }
    
    private static void createAndDisplay() {
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(test2);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


Note that I initially set the GridBagConstraints weighty to 0, and the gridheight to 1
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weightx = 0;
gbc.weighty = 0;
gbc.gridheight = 1;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
mainPanel.add(hidePanelBtn, gbc);

I then set the weighty to 1.0 and increment the gridy value as needed:
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
gbc.gridy++;
mainPanel.add(scrollPane11, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
mainPanel.add(scrollPane12, gbc);


Thx for your answer and the time you spent. This code is working fine :) but it is not what I want. I have 2 panels on another panel and I want to hide the bottompanel and make the toppanel bigger. Regarding your comment in the code, in my program I use several tabs. That is the reason for the tabbedpane. Regarding your commend for setbounds, the bottompanel is set to absolute layout. If you find some time, maybe you can have a look again. PS: I tried to add  weighty to 0, and the gridheight to 1 to the toppanel and weighty to 1.0 to the bottompanel but it was not solving the issue.

@Nisbo: please clarify -- how does the above code and my answer text not create the behavior that you are trying to achieve? What behavior is desired by not achieved by my code specificlly?

I want to hide the bottompanel and make the toppanel bigger. - from the image included with the answer, I see the text area (ie. the bottom panel) being hidden and the table (ie. the top panel) getting bigger and taking all the space. How does that not meet your requirement? the bottompanel is set to absolute layout. - which is should not be. Absolute layout is not really a layout manager and it does not allow for dynamic changes to the components.

@Hovercraft Full Of Eels You put everything to the mainPanel (Button and 2 scrollpanes) My goal is to have 2 panels on the mainPanel (GridBagLayout). The toppanel is also GridBagLayout and the bottompanel is Absolute Layout. For some reason it looks like that it (your suggestion) is not working with JPanels.

@Nisbo: My suggestion would work for JPanels or JScrollPanes, and again the top JComponent (here a JScrollPane, but it could just as easily be a JPanel) expands when the bottom is hidden. I'm still unclear on what is missing. Also, you need to be sure to set the grid bag constraints for the components going into right container.

@Hovercraft Full Of Eels I modified the code for the working example in the 1st post, maybe you can have a look and test the code. Maybe I put your suggestion on the wrong place. Regarding camickr comment, I also tried GridBagLayout for the bottom panel. But as long as it is possible I would like to stay with Absolute Layout in the bottom panel

Finally I found a solution and posted the answer. Thx for your help.
